# Multiple BERT binary classifications on a single graph to save on inference time

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, classification

I have five classes and I want to compare four of them against **one and the same class**. This isn't a One vs Rest classifier, as for each output I want to score them against one base class.

The four outputs should be: `base class vs classA`, `base class vs classB`, etc.

I could do this by having multiple binary classification tasks, but that's wasting computation time if the first layers are BERT preprocessing + pretrained BERT layers, and the only differences between the four classifiers are the last few layers of BERT (finetuned ones) and the Dense layer.

**So why not merge the graphs for more performance?**

[image]

My inputs are four different datasets, each annotated with true/false for each class.

**As I understand it, I can re-use most of the pipeline (BERT preprocessing and the first layers of BERT)**, as those have shared weights. I should then be able to train the last few layers of BERT and the Dense layer on top differently depending on the branch of the classifier (maybe using something like keras.switch?).

I have tried many alternative options including multi-class and multi-label classifiers, with actual and generated (eg, machine-annotated) labels in the case of multiple input labels, different activation and loss functions, but none of the results were acceptable to me (none were as good as the four separate models).

Is there a solution for merging the four different models for more performance, or am I stuck with using 4x binary classifiers?

Comment: When you mention "I should then be able to train the last few layers of BERT", are these few layers going to be shared later for the classification task or not? If not, then I think you should be able to extract the intermediate results from BERT and then train your classifiers on top. Otherwise, I don't think your idea could work since each task will be different, and thus you'll need a different "branch" for each one.

Answer (score 0):

When you train DNN for specific task it will be (in vast majority of cases) be better than the more general model that can handle several task simultaneously. Saying that, based on my experience the properly trained general model produces very similar results to the original binary ones. Anyways, here couple of suggestions for training strategies (assuming your training datasets for each task are completely different):

1. Weak supervision approach

   Train your binary classifiers, and label your datasets using them (i.e. label with binary classifier trained on dataset 2 datasets [1,3,4]). Then train your joint model as multilabel task using all the newly labeled datasets (don't forget to randomize samples before feeding them to trainer ;) ). Here you will need to experiment if you will use threshold and set a label to 0/1 or use the scores of the binary classifiers.
2. Create custom loss function that will not penalize if no information provided for certain class. So when your will introduce sample from (say) dataset 2, your loss will be calculated only for the 2nd class.

Of course you can apply both simultaneously. For example, if you know that binary classifier produces scores that are polarized (most results are near 0 or 1), you can use weak labels, and automatically label your data with scores. Now during the second stage penalize loss such that for score x' = 4(x-0.5)^2 (note that you get logits from the model, so you will need to apply `sigmoid` function). This way you will increase contribution of the samples binary classifier is confident about, and reduce that of less certain ones.

As for releasing last layers of BERT, usually unfreezing upper 3-6 layers is enough. Releasing more layers improves results very little and increases time and memory requirements.